# TYPO3 - canonical tag

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to add a `canonical` tag which points to another domain.

My TYPOScript looks like this:

```
temp.canonical = TEXT
temp.canonical {
  typolink {
    parameter.data = TSFE:id
    returnLast = url
  }
  wrap = <link rel="canonical" href="http://myotherdomain.com/|" />
}
page.headerData.123 < temp.canonical
```

Unfortunately this returns the full URL instead of the path which results in the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myotherdomain.com/http://example.com/subpage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny... I always have to configure the typolink

```
forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
```

to get a full link. Probably this is caused because in the most projects of me I've configured

```
config.baseUrl = http://example.com/
```

Maybe this will help you to not get a full URL but attention that your system is still working correctly after setting a baseUrl if you didn't configure it earlier. Are there maybe other settings in your config. that could be the reason for this problem?